# Spring Data findByID returns empty inner ManyToMany collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue where a `JpaRepository.findBy...()` incorrectly returns objects which have empty collections (ManyToMany), and `JpaRepository.findAll()` returns the exact same objects, for all fields, except the collections now have all the correct info.

Entities:

**Note:** the actual models for these are a more complicated, I stripped them down to avoid clutter. If any other fields or inner relationships could affect the outcome of what I'm trying to accomplish, please let me know and I'll add more information.

Bundle:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bundle")
public class Bundle implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String bundleName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="clientBundles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Client:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "client_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String clientId;
    @JoinTable(
            name = "client_bundle",
            joinColumns =  { @JoinColumn(name = "client_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "bundleName") }
    )
    @Column(name = "bundles")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Bundle> clientBundles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

For both of these I have a standard interface that extends `JpaRepository<T, ID>`.

So for example, if I have a `Bundle` that has 2 `Client`s, and I do `bundleJpaRepository.findAll()`, I can see that the `clients` collection has those 2 clients.

But if I do `bundleJpaRepository.findById(...)` I get the same `Bundle`, but the `clients` collection is 0.

Why does this happen ?

Comment: Your Bundle Entity has no PK ? (@Id in JPA slang)

Comment: Both of the entities have. I've stated that I've removed some things to avoid clutter in the question, I assumed it was an ok thing to remove. I'll edit it in.

Comment: I asked since you do your inverse join via "bundleName" field and I am almost certain it has to be the @Id other ways it will not work

Comment: I've edited it to include the Ids. The thing is, I don't get any exception. Just different collections for same objects

Comment: Remove   `@Column(name = "bundles")`

Comment: I know it's a workaround but if you are using intellij you can generate your entities from the DB

Comment: @AlanHay changing the column name didnt help

Comment: I said remove it not change it.

Comment: @AlanHay Well apparently the problem was that in such cases Spring's`JpaRepository` needs a `@Transactional`. That was what solved it. I should have added them to the question, wanting to remove clutter from the question was silly by me.